# Intellisense in .skin files in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, intellisense, skin

Is there a good way to apply intellisense in .skin files in ASP.NET 4? like a microsoft visual studio tool for example? I installed an intellisense schema for .skin files to my visual studio 2008 long time ago but it had some bugs so i had to remove it. any improvements in visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:
Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> File extensions.
Now type *skin* in the extension textbox and select *User Control Editor* from the dropdownlist. Click *Add*.

Close and reopen your .skin files and - kablam! - you now have intellisense. Be aware that it's going to complain about .skin files not having their own build provider defined in the web.config. Still better than nothing, though.

Comment: that didn't work for me :S is it a solution for the ASP.Net 4? or previous versions?

Comment: It's a website targeting .NET 4.0. It doesn't matter, however, what kind of project the .skin file is part of. I could create one with notepad, open in Visual Studio and still have the Intellisense. It's definitely working for me in VS 2010 Professional. Check this picture.
http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/571/skinintellisense.jpg

Comment: That's cool... now I need to find a project where I would actually use  skins... which are... ehm... so far... N O N E... :P

Comment: thanks a bunch.. this is also working for visual studio 2012 Express for Web.

Answer (score 4):

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
       <buildProviders>
           <add extension=".skin" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
       </buildProviders>
 </compilation>`

If you add above code in web.config file you won't get that compile time warning.